# How to access one JS file from a function inside a JS file

Tags: javascript

So, I am making a "ModReady" version of my JavaScript game where you can easily mod a game. The point is to click a button inside a ModReady version of a game, type the filepath of the mod you want to run, and the JavaScript executes it.

I have a problem though. I don't think you can run a separate .js file from inside a function.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can use require and run a separate JS file that way.

Comment: Depends. You can reliably load scripts files from your server on-demand, but that won't fly if the mod's code resides on the client machine.

Comment: Yeah...this was meant to be a moddable client. If I can afford it though I can set up a server so people can run and submit cool mods for JS games.

Comment: I'll check with my ISP and see what the deals are.

Comment: You can load local files with HTML5: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ Other then that it is quite easy: you load the file and evaluate it. Note: "easy" doesn't mean "secure".

Comment: Well, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where the game is relative to the mod authors file. The short answer is yes, but you have to be a little cunning if the mods script doesn't exist in the same place as yours.

The safest and easiest method would be to offer a version of the code base which others can download and mod themselves.

Alternatively theres several methods of running code cross browser, i wouldn't advise letting other peoples code reside on your server.

The simplest method would be similar to the way code pen or JSfiddle work, you have a text box which the mod adds the code to. Then either run your game in an iframe with the text box contents included in a script element, or store the string in a HTML 5 local storage element, load the game page querying the local storage and add the local storage string to a new script element.